# RxJS Chaining observable issues

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to change my current code, of calling an observable in another observable code by using merge map

This code does work but I know it's bad practice so I'm trying to refactor it

```
this._headerRefresh$.pipe(debounceTime(this.debounceTime)).subscribe(data => {
            this._outputProvider
                .getData(this.to.url, this.to.body ? this.to.body : undefined)
                .pipe(
                    debounceTime(this.debounceTime),
                )
                .subscribe(res => {
                    this.setstuff(res);
                });
        });
```

I tried to do it this way, but it not quite calling the this.setstuff(res)

```
this._headerRefresh$
        .pipe(
          debounceTime(this.debounceTime),
          mergeMapTo(
            this._outputProvider
              .getData(this.to.url, this.to.body ? this.to.body : undefined)
          ),
        )
        .subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.setstuff(res);
        });
```

Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: this looks ok... i question if you actually want `mergeMap` vs `switchMap` or `exhaustMap` in this case, but it seems fine otherwise... is there any error? can you recreate this in a blitz?

Comment: I need the outprovider return to use in my this.setstuff

Comment: also, is `this.to` set when you build this stream? the `To` variants expect a constant, so the inner observable is built once when the stream is built, not on each emission of the outter... does using `mergeMap(() =>` instead of `mergeMapTo(` fix the issue?

Comment: There could be a problem with using `this` inside mergeMap and inside subscribe lambdas. Most likely `this` in your case contains rxjs's this and not the object which you expect to use. I would try to run it with storing proper `this` to `self` variable

Comment: You may find [this article about rxjs and http calls](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `this.to.url` and `this.to.body` are dynamic, you can't use `mergeMapTo` ... you have to use `mergeMap` so they can be re evaluated on each emission, rather than just once when the stream is built:

```
      mergeMap(() =>
        this._outputProvider
          .getData(this.to.url, this.to.body ? this.to.body : undefined)
      ),
```

you also may really want `switchMap` or `exhaustMap` instead of `mergeMap`... the behaviors are slightly different.

with `mergeMap`, every emission of the outter will trigger the inner, and all inners will emit till they complete.  they will arrive in the order they arrive, not in the order they were triggered by the outter. so this could result in unneeded http calls in the best case, or getting stale data in the worst case.

with `switchMap`, new emissions will cause prior inner observables that are still active to cancel, and it will switch to the new call.

`exhaustMap` is sort of the opposite, it will ignore outter emissions while any inner is active. it's rarely used, but a refresh signal is the classic use case since you usually don't want to restart your refresh or trigger more while a refresh is already in flight.

Comment: I tired them all but isn't any luck, just never gets to the subscribe

Comment: you should recreate this issue in a blitz then... if it works with nested subscribes but doesn't like this, something weird is going on or information is missing